# How to parse an environment value in a string in a command?

Tags: shell

export MySQLIP="2.2.2.2"

consul kv put micro/mysql '{"enabled": true, "url":"root:yourpassword@($MySQLIP:3306)"}'

How to make $MySQLIP become 2.2.2.2 when the above command runs? I understand that this has something to do with shell scripting. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes to allow variables to be expanded:

```
consul kv put micro/mysql '{"enabled": true,
    "url":"root:yourpassword@'"$MySQLIP"':3306"}'
```

Above, we are essentially concatenating three strings, the first and last are single-quoted, and the 2nd is double quoted.  You can also write:

```
consul kv put micro/mysql "{\"enabled\": true,
        \"url\":\"root:yourpassword@$MySQLIP:3306\"}"
```

if you find it clearer.  There a many ways to quote strings in the shell.

Comment: Thank you very much, William @william-pursell. It works! Thanks for the explanatory follow-up.